# math mode parsing in NewDocumentCommand

Tags: macros

I came across the following `NewDocumentCommand` ([source](https://github.com/ajtulloch/CambridgeMathematicsPartIII/blob/master/common/common.tex#L107-L121)).

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\expn}{gg}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {%
      \Exp
    }
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {%
        \Exp\!\left(#1\right)
      }
      {%
        \Exp{#2}\!\left(#1\right)
      }
    }%
}
```

When putting in overleaf document, I noticed that it throws an error
starting at:

```
\left(#1\right)
      }
      {%
        \Exp{#2}\!\left(#1\right)
      }
    }%
}
```

The error message is:

`left can only be used in math mode`

Could anyone please assist in fixing this error? I am
new to `NewDocumentCommand`.

**EDIT:** I was asked to post a fully replicable example. Please create a `macros_math.tex` file and a `main.tex` file. In `macros_math.tex` place the following:

```
% Utility packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm,bbm,amsfonts,mathtools} %math
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{xspace} %used at the end of macros to automatically determine whether spaces should be eaten or 

\newcommand{\Exp}{\mathbb{E}}

% Expectation
\NewDocumentCommand{\expn}{gg}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {%
      \Exp
    }
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {%
        \Exp\!\left(#1\right) % offending line in overleaf!
      }
      {%
        \Exp{#2}\!\left(#1\right)
      }
    }%
}
```

In `main.tex` place the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\input{macros_math.tex} % Import the math macros we created
\title{test}
\date{February 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
$\expn{X-Y}$ % Test - this works but overleaf does not like the way the macro is constructed
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error suggests you should use `$\expn{.}{..}$`. How are you using it?

Comment: Thanks - I use it in the article as `$\expn{X - Y}$`. Which does display correctly and seems to compile fine. Just that the macro above is placed in a separate `math_macros.tex` file which I include in my main article. The `macros_math.tex` file is throwing the overleaf error and I just want to clean up the macro to stop throwing it. Does that clarify?

Comment: It's difficult to replicate the behaviour with what you're describing, as you're mentioning that the macro works, but it doesn't. Can you post something that we can replicate?

Comment: Sure, it may be an overleaf problem. I created a temporary project here replicating the issue here: https://www.overleaf.com/9983455123mgvbdccmdtzn. This is the best I can do in replicating. You can see the highlighted issue in overleaf in `macros_math.tex` for the offending line described above.

Comment: @Werner If external links are not allowed then I've pasted the code for `macros_math.tex` and `main.tex` placed in overleaf above. Hope this helps

Comment: I cannot check the output on Overleaf as it requires a login. Compiling your example locally works fine for me. The error you mentioned suggests that there is another issue before the macro definition is parsed that makes the compiler think it should typeset the `\left` delimiter.

Comment: @siracusa - thanks for checking. Yeah, I'm not sure how to resolve this error identified in overleaf? Is there a more foolproof way of writing `\left` and `\right` statements inside `NewDocumentCommand` i.e. can we write `expn` macro above more explicitly? I am new to this. Sorry I can't make it more replicable. It is just annoying seeing this error as it makes the entire `macros_math.tex` file go red in overleaf. I want to correct for this ideally

Comment: Do yourself a favor and *never* use macros with braced optional arguments. That syntax is as wrong as it can be.

Comment: @egreg - could you perhaps you can offer a better version of the same macro? The macro as written is useful to write math documents with. I'm very open to changing it but don't understand how. If you have a suggestion of how to modify it that would be really helpful to learn from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error that you can complete ignore if you never intend to compile `macros_math.tex`.

Overleaf interprets all `.tex` files as possible source files that will be compiled into an output PDF. As such, it parses the file to see whether the syntax is in order. Since it doesn't recognise the `\NewDocumentCommand` syntax as forming part of a macro definition that could be used elsewhere (inside a math environment, say), it assumes the use of `\left` and `\right` is incorrectly placed outside of math mode and shows as an error:

[image]

A way to resolve this error is to provide a different extension to `macros_math.tex`, perhaps something like `macros_math.sty`:

[image]

Remember to also change the code in your `main.tex` to `\input{macros_math.sty}`, or better, `\usepackage{macros_math}`!

Comment: thank you so much, a really informative answer. Once clarification, you mentioned to convert `macros_math.tex` to a `macros_math.sty` file and import with `usepackage{macros_math}` if I don't need to compile `macros_math.tex`. Could you please explain when I would need to compile such a macros file? I am happy to go with the `sty` and `usepackage` approach but wanted to understand any limitations going forward.

Comment: @user4687531: There's no need to compile `macros_math.tex`. It allows you to use `\input{macros_math}` (without the `.tex` extension) and is convenient, because you can insert that *anywhere* in your document. `\usepackage` requires a `.sty` and can only be used in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I will go with the `sty` approach for now. Seems to avoid the error and be useful for my purposes.